# handling basic HTTP authentication in flask

Tags: python, flask

so I have a react native front end where I make a request to my API

```
    fetch(`https://myapp.herokuapp.com/log_in/`, {
      method: 'POST', 
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(email + ":" + password)
      }
    })
```

then, in my flask api, I handle the response

```
@api.route('/log_in/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
class log_in(Resource):
    @cross_origin(origin='*')
    def get(self):

        return request.headers  #tried this, but this is empty
```

However, I have no idea how to handle the response in my flask api

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

req_json = request.get_json()
make_response(jsonify({"any_key": "any value"}), 200)

got help from : https://www.section.io/engineering-education/flask-crud-api/